# Elasticsearch: full-text search with annotated_text fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

If I have the annotated text:

```
Text1: "[Thomas Jefferson](_president_) was born in [Virginia](_place_)"
Text2: "[Thomas Jefferson](_writer_) was born in [Virginia](_place_)."
```

I'd like to be able to execute the query:

```
{
    "match_phrase": {
        "annotatedField": "_president_ was born in Virginia"
    }
}
```

and match Text1, but not Text2.
I added the annotated text using the Mapper Annotated Text Plugin.  I'm not married to this plugin, so I'm open to any way to search for custom payloads in a full-text search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the query analyzer was stripping the underscores off of my query string.  I was able to search using the annotations by changing them to

```
Text1: "[Thomas Jefferson](ispresident) was born in [Virginia](isplace)"
Text2: "[Thomas Jefferson](iswriter) was born in [Virginia](isplace)."
```

In order to use underscores, one could use a different query analyzer.